# How to know what a function in polar coordinates looks like

Tags: polar-coordinates

So I was wondering if there are any good ways of figuring out how a function $r(\theta)$ looks like. Besides just trying out and plotting the points. In some simple cases we can show that $r=2\cos(\theta)$, for example, is a circle by showing it fulfills $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2$. However, there are many other things than circles. For example the rose, $r=\cos(3\theta)$ how would you know how it looks like? Also, how would you find out the values of $\theta$ that bind one such petal?

Comment: There isn't a single good way other than experience. Draw lots of them, try to figure out why it looks the way it does, and after a while you start to develop an intuition, just like you do for regular cartesian graphs.

Comment: You ask, at first, the same questions you'd ask for a graph: which is the range of values for $r$, at which points does it reach its maximum end its minimum, where is it concave and convex... (that is enough to understand the petal figure, for example).Then you can ask more refined questions like computing curvature and finding vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, $r=\sin(\frac 1{\theta})$ looks like a mouse's face:

[image]